# How can I avoid the margin added by axvspan

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I want to shade half of the background of a scatter plot to distinguish two different regimes.

I have tried to use `axvspan` to do so. However, I have the problem that whenever I apply the axvspan, matplotlib adds a margin to the latter resulting in an ugly gap between the shading and the axis bounding box. How can I avoid this?

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

nsamp = 50
x = np.random.rand(nsamp)
y = np.random.rand(nsamp)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8, 8))
ax.scatter(x, y)
ax.use_sticky_edges = True
_, xmax = plt.gca().get_xlim()
ax.axvspan(0.5, xmax=xmax, color="#97999B", zorder=-1)
plt.show()
```

**
Result:**

[image]

Comment: `ax.set_xlim(right=xmax)`?

Comment: Thank you @BigBen , I see your point. My MWE wasn't specific enough. I want the axvspan always reaching the axis bounding box depending on the data.

Comment: This is [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045767/how-can-i-change-the-x-axis-so-there-is-no-white-space) you need. `ax.margins(x=0)`

Comment: ... except this also changes the left x-margin, which may be undesirable.

Comment: Also `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8, 8), tight_layout=True)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib: make objects ignored by axis autoscaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66805192/matplotlib-make-objects-ignored-by-axis-autoscaling)

Comment: specifically, a call to `ax.add_artist(plt.Rectangle((0.5, -1), 1, 3, facecolor="#97999B", zorder=-1))` seems to work well with your example, but has more hard-coded values that might not work if you want them autocalculated based on things you add to the plot later